# Python and xml : Reading data from xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have a simple python, in which i have defined styledoc as follows

```
styledoc = libxml2.parseDoc("""
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
  xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
  xmlns:foo='http://example.com/foo'
  xsl:exclude-result-prefixes='foo'>

  <xsl:param name='bar'>failure</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match='/'>
    <article><xsl:value-of select='foo:foo($bar)'/></article>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
""")
```

I want to have something like all the data included in a file read.xml and something like this

```
styledoc = libxml2.parseDoc("read.xml");
```

but it gives me an error 'read' is not defined. What mistake am I doing?

Comment: We need the exact error and the exact code that causes it (propably including a bit of context).

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `libxml2.parseFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseDoc` takes a string containing XML, as shown in your first example. To parse a file use `parseFile` instead:

```
styledoc = libxml2.parseFile("read.xml")
```